# Couldnt get neo4j-android-client.jar and neo4j-android-common.jar after building the github project

Tags: android, ant, neo4j

I am working trying to build android project with neo4j database.

I took the source from this github link "https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-mobile-android". 
I am able to run the demo project and got neo4j-android.jar file. 
But to proceed further with my case, I need two more jar files. One is neo4j-android-common.jar which I should get in neo4j-android-common/bin folder. And another is, neo4j-android-client.jar which I should get in neo4j-android-client/bin folder.

But I am not getting these jars in respective bin folders. I tried to build project several times. I have everything in bin folder except the jars.

Please help me, if anyone has resolved this error before.

Thanks in advance and it will be a great help.

Comment: are you using android-studio

Comment: Yes I am using android studio nagabhushan

Answer (score 1):

When you build neo4j-android-service the two jars you are looking for are created, only they are not renamed from classes.jar to neo4j-android-common.jar and neo4j-android-client.jar. Look for classes.jar in the neo4j-android-common\bin and the neo4j-android-client\bin folders.